Dominated convergence theorem for $L^{\infty}$ with additionnal hypothesis of vanishing at infinity
Let $f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$. Denote $\chi_R$ the characteristic function on $B(0,R)\subset\mathbb{R}^n.$ If $\underset{\|x\|\to \infty}{\text{lim}} f(x) = 0$, then will
$\underset{R\to \infty}{\text{lim}} \|(1-\chi_R) f\|_{\infty} = 0?$
Obviously, without the vanishing assumption, it doesn't work (for instance, if $n=1$ and $f = \text{cos}$, then $\|(1-\chi_R) f\|_{\infty} = 1, \; \forall R > 0).$
My idea was to say (by absurd) that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. there always exists some $R > 0$ as big as we want with $\|(1-\chi_R) f\|_{\infty} \geq \varepsilon$. However, by definition of the limit, one takes $\varepsilon > \delta > 0$ s.t. $|f(x)| < \delta$ for almost all $x$ outside the ball of radius $R'>0$. Taking some $R > R'$ with $\|(1-\chi_R) f\|_{\infty} \geq \varepsilon$ then yields $|f(x)| < \delta <\|(1-\chi_R) f\|_{\infty}$ for almost all $x$ outside the ball of radius $R$ which seems to be a contradiction since $\|(1-\chi_R) f\|_{\infty} = \underset{\| x\| > R}{\text{ess sup}} |f(x)|$ is supposed to be the smallest upper bound but we found another one, namely $\delta$.
Is that right?

This has nothing to do with the DCT, and "decreasing" assumes some monotonicity, wheareas you only want convergence to $0$. And "the smaller" should be "the smallest", or "the least". That said, your proof is correct, but could be much shorter. You don't need to reason by contradiction: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x) = 0$, there exists $R$ such that $|f(x)|\le\varepsilon$ outside $B(0,R)$, therefore, $|(1-\chi_R) f|_{\infty}\le\varepsilon$.

I used "DCT" because in a $L^p$ space it would be immediate by the DCT, but it doesn't work for $p= \infty$. You're right for the rest, I meant "vanishing" and I could have avoided to proceed by contradiction, my bad.

Dominated convergence is used in problems of integration ($L_p$ spaces with $0<p<\infty$). In your case, you are not dealing with integration of a collection of functions, but about the "size" of sets where a function is below certain level. Notice that if $f$ is measurable function, $C$ is a positive number and  $|f|\leq C$ almost surely, then $\|f\|_\infty\leq C$. Indeed,
$\mu(|f|>C+\varepsilon)=0$ for all $\varepsilon\geq0$ and so,  by definition of $\|\;\|_\infty$,
$$\|f\|_\infty=\inf\{a>0:\mu(|f|>a)=0\}\leq C$$
In you problem, $\lim_{\|x\|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$ implies that given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $a>0$ such that if $|x|\geq R$, then $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$. Thus, for $r>a$, $$\big|(1-\mathbb{1}_{B(0;r)})f\big|=|f|\mathbb{1}_{\{x:|x|\geq r\}}<\varepsilon$$
and so,
$$\|f-f\mathbb{1}_{B(0;r)}\|_\infty\leq\varepsilon\qquad\text{whenever}\quad r\geq a$$
